# Swiping through buttons. Adobe Flash, as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am creating a piano app, what i want to happen that when the finger of the user goes through all of the keys without lifting, all the keys that has been pressed will produce sound.

Answer (score 1):

Capture `MOUSE_OVER` and `MOUSE_OUT` events and handle the sounds accordingly:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, startSound);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopSound);

function startSound(me:MouseEvent):void {
    // Start the sound.
}
function stopSound(me:MouseEvent):void {
    // Stop the sound.
}
```